# How to make only the owner of a Product able to edit or delete it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am developing a supplier management system. I have different admins and different suppliers, i will like that only the particular supplier that added the product is able to edit or delete it, so that even other suppliers are not able to edit or delete it.

And also, how can we make only the owner of a product see the edit or delete product button when viewing all products.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@supplier_required
def Editproduct(request, pk):
    title = "Edit Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = AddProductForm(instance=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Product Edited Successfully")
            return redirect('product')

    context = {"form":form, "title":title}

    return render(request, "core/editproduct.html", context)

@login_required
@supplier_required
def DeleteProduct(request, pk):
    title = "Delete Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    try:
        product.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Product Deleted Successfully.")
        return redirect('product')
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Failed to Delete Product.")
        return redirect('product')
```

products.html

```
{% for product in all_products %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height: 200px!important;" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title mb-3">
                <span>{{product.name}}</span>
                <span style="float: right;">
                    <form action="{% url 'add-favourite' product.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline-flex;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit">
                            {% if product.favourited_by_user %}
                                <i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="fas fa-star m-r-10"></i>
                            {% else %}
                                <i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="far fa-star m-r-10"></i>
                            {% endif %}
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    {% if request.user.user_type.is_supplier %}
                    <a href="{% url 'edit-product' product.id %}"><i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-10"></i></a>
                    <a href="{% url 'delete-product' product.id %}"><i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a>
                    {% endif %}
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">
                <span>Price: {{product.price}}</span>
                <span style="float: right;">Quantity: {{product.quantity}}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Add a foreign key from product to supplier and write a decorator to check if the product's supplier is same as current user?

Comment: can you please provide a code for that, i don't really understand

Comment: Although looking at your code you have `form.instance.user = request.user` does your `Product` model have a foreign key to user?

Comment: yes it does. that line of code makes the current logged in user assigned to any product added, so he doesn't need to fill a field of which supplier owns the product.

Comment: I don't see that field in the model can you please add it.

Comment: it is there, i was trying to make the code not too long, that was why i removed some fields. I added it it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the `user` field:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
@supplier_required
def Editproduct(request, pk):
    title = 'Edit Product'
    #                            filter on the user ↓
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk, user=request.user)

    form = AddProductForm(instance=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product Edited Successfully')
            return redirect('product')

    context = {'form': form, 'title': title}

    return render(request, 'core/editproduct.html', context)
```

If the user is not the owner, they will see a HTTP 404 response.

Comment: in my templates, how can i make only the owner of the product see the delete or edit button on the product, similar to the way stackoverflow comments works. I have edited the question and added the templates.

Comment: @coderboy: in the template you work with a condition `{% if product.user == request.user %}... render button{% endif %}`. But by altering the view, the button will simply not work even if it is shown in the template.

Answer (score 1):

According the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-proxy-models), you can define a custom `has_perm` method in your `User` class using the `obj` parameter that "check for a permission for [...] this specific object":

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):

        if(perm == 'product.edit_or_delete'):
            if(instanceof(obj, Product)):
                if(obj.owner == self):
                    return True

        return True

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)


@login_required
@supplier_required
def Editproduct(request, pk):
    title = "Edit Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = AddProductForm(instance=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            if(request.user.has_perm('product.edit_or_delete',form.instance)):
                form.instance.user = request.user
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Product Edited Successfully")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "User does not have permission to this Product.")
            return redirect('product')

    context = {"form":form, "title":title}

    return render(request, "core/editproduct.html", context)

@login_required
@supplier_required
def DeleteProduct(request, pk):
    title = "Delete Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    try:
        if(request.user.has_perm('product.edit_or_delete',form.instance)):
            product.delete()
            messages.success(request, "Product Deleted Successfully.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "User does not have permission to this Product.")
        return redirect('product')
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Failed to Delete Product.")
        return redirect('product')
```

You can also use [django-role-permissions](https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/object_permissions.html):

```py
from rolepermissions.permissions import register_object_checker

@register_object_checker()
def edit_or_delete_product(user, product):

    if product.owner == user:
        return True

    return False

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)


@login_required
@supplier_required
def Editproduct(request, pk):
    title = "Edit Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = AddProductForm(instance=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            if has_object_permission('edit_or_delete_product', user, product):
                form.instance.user = request.user
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Product Edited Successfully")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "User does not have permission to this Product.")
            return redirect('product')

    context = {"form":form, "title":title}

    return render(request, "core/editproduct.html", context)

@login_required
@supplier_required
def DeleteProduct(request, pk):
    title = "Delete Product"
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    try:
        if has_object_permission('edit_or_delete_product', user, product):
            product.delete()
            messages.success(request, "Product Deleted Successfully.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "User does not have permission to this Product.")
        return redirect('product')
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Failed to Delete Product.")
        return redirect('product')
```